# How to strong permit parameters for a model which as has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associationship

User has one Profile

Profile has many Images

While creating the user, I want the profile and Images to be updated at single time.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Here is the Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.create(get_params)
  end

  private
  def get_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, profile_attributes: [:address, images_attributes: [:image_url]])
  end
end
```

The JSON that is sent to create action is

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "vamsi",
        "profile_attributes": {

              "address": "my home address",

            "images_attributes": {
                "0": {
                    "image_url": "url1"
                },
                "1": {
                    "image_url": "url2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is this

```
Started POST "/create_user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-04 18:55:01 +0530
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by UsersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"vamsi", "profile_attributes"=>{"address"=>"my home address", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image_url"=>"url1"}, "1"=>{"image_url"=>"url2"}}}}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Here is a sample app which has the above associations set up
https://github.com/vamsipavanmahesh/sample_association

Comment: Can you check what are the errors by debugging `@user.errors.messages`

Comment: {:"profile.user"=>["must exist"], :"profile.images.profile"=>["must exist"]}
 this is what I am getting

Comment: seems like the issue is you have presence validations on `user_id` in profile model and `profile_id` in image model

Comment: but rails tries to validate those fields before saving the user and profile model

Comment: I don't have any validations like that, whatever code I have is what I mentioned there as well as in the github repo

Comment: @gates it seems as though you don't really ask a question here. You state `While creating the user, I want the profile and Images to be updated at single time.`, but you never say what it does INSTEAD of what you want it to do.

Comment: @Pachonk Well I want it to create a user with a profile and multiple images under the profile, but the transaction is rolling back. I am not sure about permitting models with has_one association